# Linq Sum Columns including joins

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have two tables.
`[Table.Game]`
Columns are  `"PK_id"` `"username"` and `"couponID"`
`[Table.Coupons]`
Columns are `"PK_id"` `"CouponID"` and `"Points"`
The two columns `"CouponID"` are associated with eachother. Let say i have two rows with the user "harry" in `[Table.Game]` this person has two different `couponID`.
In `[Table.Coupons]` this user "harry" has `"CouponID"` 1 and 2. Column `"Points"` have 10 and 20.

To the question how do u sum this two different point values that have different `"CouponIDs"`. This does work if i have only one `"CouponId"`. But not when the user has 2 different CouponIDs. Values is 0

```
var points = (from p in linq.Coupons
              join g in linq.games on p.couponID equals g.couponID
              where g.username == username && g.couponID == p.couponID
              select (int)p.win).Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

you already join the tables on the `CouponID` don't need it in the `where`:

```
var points = (
    from p in linq.Coupons
    join g in linq.games on p.couponID equals g.couponID
    where g.username == username
    select (int)p.win).Sum();
```

Comment: i forgot to mention. That g.username == username give the specific information about the "profile" for the requested person. So if visit person "harry" on myhomepage.com g.username == harry. So i can se this specific persons points. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using single to many relations instead of many to many in my database.